# How can I flatten a nested dictionary containing lists and dicts in values and export it as a spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a problem with a very nested dictionary in Python. It is of the following example:

```
mydict = {'Carcompany': {'Brand': 'Ford',
  'Factory': {'Country': 'Germany',
   'Workers': {'Engineers': '150', 'Mechanics': '200'},
   'FactoryDetails': [{'FactoryCode': '1',
     'FactoryCity': 'Cologne',
     'FactoryCityDetail': [{'Shifts': 'Day',
       'Days': '7'},
      {'Shifts': 'Night', 'Days': '5'}]},
    {'FactoryCode': '2',
     'FactoryCity': 'Berlin',
     'FactoryCityDetail': {'Shifts': 'Night',
      'Days': '5'}}]}}}
```

So there are values containing list of dicts containing values with lists of dicts again. The depth varies and my goal is an excel spreadsheet or a relational database table like this:

[image]

I have tried to flatten the dictionary by pd.io.json.json_normalize() to get a pandas dataframe, find the lists, explode the columns and flatten them again. This solution is really slow and fails with deeper and more nested situations.

My idea is to use a recursive approach, but everything I have found on stackoverflow so far fails when it comes to lists of dictionaries (because of updating dict values) or return enumerated single lines for each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you've looked into `flatten_json` [Flatten JSON](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten). I used it to write a recursive function for my complex JSON - [flatten_json recursive flattening function for lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232436/flatten-json-recursive-flattening-function-for-lists)